# Is there a software allow me to use one pc to control other two pc?

Tags: remote-desktop

I have PC1,PC2 anb PC3. I want to use PC1 to remote desktop control PC2 and PC3 simultaneously.Is there a software can do this?

Comment: Which operating system? If you are in a Microsoft environment you can use remote desktop. There are commercial products like team viewer if your PC have diff os. Under linux you many options for this.

Comment: windows. team viewer can do this?I use  team viewer personal version now,but can not do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dualmon Remote Access (dualmon.com) - You can be connected to multiple computers at the same time, and it installs on Windows.